# Marshalling wchar_*t via pinvoke in c# does not return its value back to StringBuilder

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, marshalling, wchar-t

First of all I want to say that I know enough about c++ and pinvoke to be frustrated.

I am currently working on a c++ wrapper and pinvoke that is not returning the info I need.

Below are the pieces of what I am doing:
I have a c++ method with the signature of:

```
DllExport int LookupFamilyName(__in PCWSTR familyName,__out_opt wchar_t* result, int lengthIn)
```

With the internal code:

```
UINT32 count = 0;
UINT32 length = 0;

LONG rc = GetPackagesByPackageFamily(familyName, &count, NULL, &length, NULL);
if (rc == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    return int(rc);
}
else if (rc != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)  //122
{
    return int(rc);
}

PWSTR *fullNames = (PWSTR *) malloc(count * sizeof(*fullNames));

if (fullNames == NULL)
{
    return 700010; //faile to allocate memeory
}

PWSTR buffer = (PWSTR) malloc(length * sizeof(WCHAR));
if (buffer == NULL)
{
    return 700011; //faile to allocate memeory
}

rc = GetPackagesByPackageFamily(familyName, &count, fullNames, &length, buffer);


if (rc != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    return int(rc);
}
else
{
    result = new wchar_t[lengthIn];
    for (UINT32 i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        wcscpy_s(result,lengthIn,fullNames[i]);
    }
}
free(buffer);
free(fullNames);
```

I am then using the following to invoke:

```
    [DllImport("ClassLibrary1.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern int LookupFamilyName(string familyName, ref StringBuilder sbPackageFullName, int len);
```

And then I am calling it from C# with the following:

```
string packagename = "Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe";
StringBuilder showmethemoney = new StringBuilder(64);
int x = LookupFamilyName(packagename, ref showmethemoney,showmethemoney.Capacity);
```

I'm passing in a StringBuilder for the wchar_t* and that value is filled in with what I want by the time we get to the end of the LookupFamilyName method but when we get back to the c# code, the StringBuilder does not have the value that the wchar_t* had in the c++ code.

For those of you that know far more then I, what do I need to do to make sure that the the value in the wchar_t* result gets passed back to the StringBuilder?

Comment: You declared the 2nd argument to be wchar_t**.  Delete `ref`.

Comment: I Removed the ref from the pinvoke call and the c# code, but the StringBuilder is still empty upon return.

Comment: Next bug is `result = new wchar_t[lengthIn];`, delete that line.

Comment: Hans, That was it. Those two changes made all the difference! Working like a charm now.